# Saving email from cPanel and integrating it to postfix.

Tags: centos, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I have a shared hosting environment with cPanel installed managing all email creation, forwarding and all other tasks. But now I have moved to VPS using CentOs and already installed postfix, dovecot, roundcube and set up an email server. Now I need to migrate my emails from the cPanel and into the VPS. What I would like to know is the process of integrating those mails to Postfix/dovecot.

I have saved the entire `mail` folder from my cPanel. `public_html/username/mail` which has many emails. I would like to know if someone has done the same thing and successfully migrated their servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

postfix is not involved in a simple maildir migration. postfix just transfers incoming and outgoing mail, mail storage is dovecot's job.

it is possible to transfer the contents of a maildir onto a new server, dovecot should load the messages just fine. however, if you're doing it this way there is a chance you mess up file permissions, message flags, folder separators etc.

I'd recommend using a tool like [imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/) or a service like [migrationwiz](https://www.migrationwiz.com/) instead which makes the migration process very easy, you basically just give them account data for both servers and let the tool handle the rest.